# The IN operator is provided with too many operands; number of operands: 119 dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

Try to use IN operation in dynamodb but get following error. Could anyone help me with alternative solution ?

var params = {

```
TableName : "table_name",
FilterExpression : "id IN ("+Object.keys(profileIdObject).toString()+ ")",
ExpressionAttributeValues : profileIdObject
```

};

ERROR :: 
{

```
  "message": "Invalid FilterExpression: The IN operator is provided with too many operands; number of operands: 119",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2018-02-13T08:48:02.597Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 25.08276239472692
```

}

Answer (score 9):

According to docs:

> The maximum number of operands for the IN comparator is 100

Found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-expression-parameters

You will need to perform the query/scan in multiple batches, in your case with 100 of `Object.keys(profileIdObject).toString()` in the first batch and 19 in the second batch.  Then coalesce the results.

Comment: if you're searching specific items its okay but how about to avoid items ? like

not Id IN(.....) how can you handle it for the next batch query ? because if I do the same for the next one, it will return the items that I wanted to avoid in the previous query, do you got it ?

Answer (score 6):

According to dynamodb documentation, the maximum number of operands for the IN comparator is 100

So you can split into many operations like :

`FilterExpression : "id IN (1,2,3, ....) OR id IN (101,102,103,...) ..."`

Using this function   :

```
let getFilterExp = function (x) {
    let arr = []
    let currentIndex = 0
    let counter = 0
    let max = 99

    arr[currentIndex] = {}

    for (let y in x) {
        if (counter < max) {
            arr[currentIndex][y] = x[y]
            counter++
        }
        else {
            currentIndex++
            arr[currentIndex] = {}
            arr[currentIndex][y] = x[y]
            counter = 0
        }
    }

    let exp = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            exp += "id IN (" + Object.keys(arr[i]).toString() + ")"
        }
        else {
            exp += " OR id IN (" + Object.keys(arr[i]).toString() + ") "
        }
    }

    return exp
}
```

Where x is the profileIdObject in your case

```
let filterExp = getFilterExp(profileIdObject )
```